# why does javascript parse an array as a string when passed in as an argument or as an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

consider this code

example 1:

```
function plus(a) {return a+10}
([1]) // "110"
```

example 2:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr[[1]] // 2
arr.splice([1],1);
arr // (6) [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

can someone explain why passing in an array as an argument, gets converted to a string? (that's what it looks like happened here)

Comment: the + operator is not for arrays. if you want to add to an array use name_of_the_array.push(newElement)

Comment: You are invoking the toString on [1] it seems

Comment: Why you passing in an array as the argument when the function expects a string?

Answer (score 0):

> can someone explain why passing in an array as an argument

It doesn't.

It gets treated as an array right up until the point where you try to use [the addition operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) on it.

It hits the step *Let rprim be ? ToPrimitive(rval)* and converts it according to [those rules](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive).

And so on until it calls [the array's `toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).

---

Similar rules apply in the other examples.

In short: When it makes no sense at all to use an array in a given context, type conversion is applied to turn it into a data type that is apropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1 - you get a string from the [array.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) so you need to cast back to number - here I use +

```js
function plus(a) {return +a+10}
console.log(plus([1]))
```

Second

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(arr[1]) // 2
console.log(arr[[1]]) // 2

arr.splice([1],1); // removes the second item 
console.log(arr) 

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr.splice(1,1);          //  just as if you had done this
console.log(arr) //  [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: and for the second example?

Answer (score 0):

The + operator doesn't work for arrays. It only works for numbers or strings.

Since javascript can't use your array with the + operator, it converts it to string before. That's why `plus([1])` is `"110"`

You can use the push method if you want to add to an array:

```
  array.push(newElement);
```

In the second example, inside splice, your array is used with an operator that doesn't support it so it is converted to a number. If you look at the [MDN definition of splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you see it expects a number, not an array.

When you want to use splice, you don't pass an array as the first argument, you pass the index of the first element to remove. If you want to remove 2 from your array, you do arr.splice(1,1);

Comment: and for the second example?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript automatically outputs a certain data type when two different data types are added.

Here are two examples:

```js
2 + 3 // 5
2 + "hello" // "2hello"
```

When two numbers are added, an integer is output. However, `2` and `hello` can't be added numerically, so everything is first automatically converted to a string, and then appended.

The same thing happens in your case – `a` remains an array, but an array can't be added to a number. So both are converted to strings and then appended, and the end result is a string.

You were probablly thinking of adding a value to the end of an array. This is done using:

```js
a.push(10);
```

Or, if you wanted to add the first item in the array and `10` to get the result `11`, use:

```js
return a[0] + 10
```

But you can't add a single number to a whole array, only to one of the items or at the end of the array.